# File appears to be corrupted when added as a mail attachment

Tags: c#, smtp, mailmessage

I have this property on my model:

```cs
public class FileUploadModel {
   public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

and I'm trying to add this file as an attachment, like so:

```cs
...
            foreach(FileUploadModel attachment in attachments)
            {
                var file = new Attachment(attachment.File.InputStream, attachment.File.FileName, attachment.File.ContentType);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(file);
            }
...
```

But when I open this on the mail, the file is not readable. I tried uploading pdf and png files for now, but the result is conclusive that I may be doing something wrong.

EDIT: Upon inspection, I discovered that the byte array of the input stream are all zeroes.

Comment: Can you save the file and open it outside of your mail client?

Comment: I did, it still looks corrupted